# Newbie question about Spreadsheet and Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It is wrong to use spreadsheet and sheet like this?

```
function ADD_COLUMN() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B:B').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 1).activate();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue()+1);
    var addedDateAndTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM yyyy");
    sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(addedDateAndTime)
};
```

This script adds a column between A and B columns, inserts the value of (C1 --This cell is B1 before the bew column is created-- + 1) into B1 and and the current date (month and year) into B2.

I have not much familiarity with scripts and made this one from bits of other scripts, so if this script is wrong then can someone please explain in a simple way why is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a column "between" `A` and `B` and then insert the mentioned values, you might benefit from taking a look at the below code:

```
function ADD_COLUMN() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertColumns(2, 1);
  sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue()+1);
  var addedDateAndTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM yyyy");
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(addedDateAndTime)
}
```

The most notable change, however, is the fact according to [Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), it's best to call a service only once - hence storing the value of `spreadsheet` and `sheet`. Also, since you only want to *insert a column*, there is no need to activate the range from the sheet.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script
  Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation / Issues:

- The issue in your logic is that you add an additional column before A and B and therefore the value that belongs to cell `C1` get shifted to `D1`. Then, when you use `sheet.getRange(1,3)` you get the new value of cell `C1` which might not be what you want. I would advice you to get the value of column `3` plus the number of columns you add before that:

  `sheet.getRange(1,3+columnsToAdd)`

  In this way, the previous value of `C1` will be used to calculate the value for cell `B1`.
- In Google Apps Script you don't need to set active ranges or sheets to copy or paste data. These `setActive` methods are used by automatically created macros to show you the steps of your script in the `ui`, but you hardly even need them unless you have another reason to.
- [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) objects and [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) are instances of two **different** classes. Meaning that they use different methods. Read the documentation of the links I provided, to see why each instance is used and for what scenario.

### Solution:

```
function ADD_COLUMN() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const columnsToAdd = 1; 
    ss.insertColumnsBefore(2, columnsToAdd);
    sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(sheet.getRange(1,3+columnsToAdd).getValue()+1);
    const addedDateAndTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM yyyy");
    sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(addedDateAndTime);
};
```

Comment: Yes, I have read that documentation but is not so clear for a beginner with little time to understand the whole document, hence my initial question. Thanks for your time and your answer.